# Why does using prop.children on a Rebass Box component output a console.error in Chrome?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components, rebass

I have an app built with NextJS and I have a component composed from  the Rebass Library which works, but it gives this warning in the console:

[image]

Here is the component:

```js
// Container.js

import { Box } from "rebass"

export const Container = (props) => (
  <Box
    sx={{
      maxWidth: "1240px",
      mx: "auto",
      px: 3,
    }}
  >
    {props.children}
  </Box>
)
```

And the index component:

```js
import { Container } from "./Container"

const Index = (props) => (
  <Container>
    <div>Hello, World</div>
  </Container>
)

export default Index
```

How can I get rid of this error message?

Comment: I don't get this error anymore but I don't know what I did to fix it.  The above two components remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

So it had nothing to do with the above components but rather another component in another file.

```js
// Navbar.js

import { Flex, Link, Text } from "rebass"

import { Container } from "./Container"

export const Nav = (props) => (
  <Container>
    <Flex
      px={2}
      height={70}
      color="white"

      sx={{ background: `${(props) => props.theme.colors.background}` }} 
      // Using the line above causes the error

      sx={{ background: "background" }} // use this line instead

      alignItems="center"
    >
      <Text p={2} fontWeight="bold">
        Company
      </Text>
      <Flex mx="auto" />
      <Link variant="nav" href="#!">
        Link
      </Link>
    </Flex>
  </Container>
)
```

This is the prescribed way to get a themed value into a Rebass component.  It didn't work for me so that is why I tried a function.